# Entity Framework Core - get script of pending migrations

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Is there a way to determine the migration script(s) used when running

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

In EF6, I could use a

```
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorScriptingDecorator
```

and the method

```
migrator.ScriptUpdate(null, null)
```

to generate the scripts so I could dump them for troubleshooting purposes if something went wrong. Is there a similar approach for ef-core?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to dumping the Entity Framework Core SQL scripts for troubleshooting, or adding them to source control for use in a CI/CD pipeline with a tool like [Roundhouse](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse).

See: [EFCoreHelper.cs](https://github.com/jeremylarter/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/GetStarted/EFCoreHelper.cs)

```cs
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetAllMigrationsSQL(DbContext db)
{            
    var migrationsSQL = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var migrations = db.Database.GetMigrations();
    var migrator = db.GetService<IMigrator>();
    string fromMigration = null;
    foreach(var toMigration in migrations)
    {
        var sql = migrator.GenerateScript(fromMigration, toMigration);
        migrationsSQL.Add(toMigration, sql);
        fromMigration = toMigration;
    }
    return migrationsSQL;
}
```

The using statements to get the code working are:

```cs
using System; //for the Console output
using System.Collections.Generic; //for the Dictionary type
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
```

I have [forked the EFGetStarted project](https://github.com/jeremylarter/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/GetStarted) to demonstrate how to use the code. The SQL will be generated and logged to the console. The example used produces the following SQL:

```sql
--20190917222642_InitialCreate
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
    "MigrationId" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY,
    "ProductVersion" TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "Blogs" (
    "BlogId" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Blogs" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Url" TEXT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "Posts" (
    "PostId" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Posts" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Title" TEXT NULL,
    "Content" TEXT NULL,
    "BlogId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Posts_Blogs_BlogId" FOREIGN KEY ("BlogId") REFERENCES "Blogs ("BlogId") ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX "IX_Posts_BlogId" ON "Posts" ("BlogId");

INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20190917222642_InitialCreate', '3.1.8');
```

Thanks to Jiří Činčura [Generating Entity Framework Core Migrations script from code](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/id/233651)